# How can I track subscription renewals in Apple Newstand?

Tags: ios, reporting, newsstand-kit

How can I report on subscription renewals of our Newsstand publication?

We need this to get an accurate idea of what cost per acquisition we should be offering our marketing partners and are really struggling to get this information.

Is this done via the SDK, or can we get it from Apple?